# How can I test my websites download speed

Tags: php, web, pagespeed

I bought a website hosting Plan and I want to test my websites download Speed. My website is [jm26.net](https://jm26.net)
By test I mean, I want to know how fast my websites download Speed is.

I hope you can understand what I mean, thank you

Edit: I uploaded a 100MB temp file: https://jm26.net/test/100MB.bin

Comment: https://gprivate.com/608yu

Comment: testing website speed as download speed is subjective(is a free world so if you want to get the wrong direction and waste time you'll find many https://www.google.com/search?q=website+speed+tool) ; instead the solution :   local benchmark with apache tools  ab /abs  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html  ; ab.ex (windows) or .\ab(linux) as external observer and stress tool will provide not exact results and never equal so you must use it to find out how many executions are done in eg a second  let say 10 experiments and then add all of them then divide to 10

Comment: (arithmetic mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean )  and so these basic experiments you'll do =statistic math= will be close answer to your question ;  then as final experiment : try to download and install in xamp  open sources  cms then test them! allways how many per seccond!     eg: asuming your website is in folder example1 in xampp directory try paste this in a cmd shell console: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\ab.exe" -t 1 -c 100 -l -n 5000 http://localhost/example1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a tool by Google: https://pagespeed.web.dev/ that you can use.